# If else statement in tidyverse to find and sum values above x number of standard deviations from the mean

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like so:

```
set.seed(560)
df<-data.frame(month= rep(1:40, each=30), precip= rep(rnorm(30, 20, 
10)),temp=rnorm(30, 50, 10))
```

In the distribution of `precip` and `temp` values for each `month` subset, if the value is  greater than 2 standard deviations(sd) above the mean, then I want to get a count of how many values are above the 2 sd. I will call this variable `count`

I would like to use an argument within a tidyverse function to achieve this

```
df<-  
df %>%
group_by(month)%>%
summarise(count= count(precip> 2*sd(precip))
```

The `output` df would have the following format. (Note: values in the `count` column below are not accurate counts based on the example `df` above. Rather just an example for expected output):

```
output<-data.frame(month= rep(1:40,1), precip= rep(rnorm(40, 20, 
10)),temp=rnorm(40, 50, 10), count= sample(1:30, 40, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: You want the output to have the same number of rows as the input? So it the count value repeated for all observations for the same month? Then just use `mutate()` add a new column rather than `summarize()`.

Comment: Changing `count` to `sum` will do: `df %>% group_by(month)%>% summarise(count = sum(precip> 2*sd(precip))`

Comment: @Jaap I get NAs if i use your method

Comment: @MrFlick The output should summarise the frequency at which values are above 2 standard deviations for a monthly distribution of the values. Therefore, the input df has multiple measurements  for a month. The output will only be one value per month.

Comment: That is because you have missing values, therefore add `na.rm = TRUE` to `sum` to get the right output.

Comment: @Jaap I have tried adding the `na.rm=TRUE` argument, and get an output, however that method is still not giving the correct output. For example, in month 1 the mean=19.28 and 1sd=8.2 thus 2sd=16.4. Thus any value above 35.68 or below 2.88  (19.28+/-16.4) would satisfy the requirement. In month 1 only 2 values satisfy this argument so the `count` row for month 1 would read 2. Using your solution I get 19 for the count rather than 2

Comment: you will then need something like `df %>%  group_by(month) %>%  summarise(count = sum(precip > (mean(precip) + 2*sd(precip)) | precip < (mean(precip) - 2*sd(precip))) )`